# Why window.onload not executing in $.get(

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

```
$.get("MyPage.aspx", {foo:"bar"}, function(results){
  Some Js code here.
});
```

**Question** - In MyPage.aspx, I have `window.onload` method. This is not being executed.

Your comments?

Comment: Because the window is already loaded.

Comment: @Stefan - What should be done to execute the .js code of MyPage.aspx load ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$.get()` only retrieves a file from the web server.

It is the browser that executes `window.onload` etc. if the HTML file is **displayed**. If you just load the file to retrieve its content, no client-side JS code is executed.

Comment: I have to execute .js code of MyPage.aspx when page is completely downloaded and before the ajax call starts...

Answer (score 1):

window.onload does not fire again just because you fetch some new HTML with an ajax call.  There's only one window.onload event per document.

The `.get()` call already has a completion function when the ajax call is done.  Do your work from that completion call.

The only ways I know of to trigger the desired code in the loaded code are to first put that code into your document and then:

1. Instead of waiting for onload to execute, call the desired function in the loaded code you want to execute manually after the ajax call is done (e.g. the same code that would execute in the onload).
2. Put the content into an iframe (which will then get its own onload event).

Comment: @ytftyffty - I added some more info to my answer.

Comment: I have to execute .js code of MyPage.aspx when page is completely downloaded and before the ajax call starts...

Comment: @ytftyffty - huhhh?  You want to execute code before you've fetched it?  It's the ajax call that retrieves the code.  You can't execute the code in there until AFTER the ajax call has completed and the code has been retrieved.

Comment: Yes. I want to only execute js code of this page after it is downloaded on the client end and before Ajax call starts.

Comment: @ytftyffty - what you are asking for makes no sense!  The code is only available when the ajax call is done.  It is NOT available any sooner than that.  Perhaps you should back up and describe the overall problem you're trying to solve because you will need a different approach.